# facebook like can't decode %3F to question mark

Tags: facebook-like, decode, encode

I'm using like button with href which contains query string. like this:

```
"http://www.test.com/index.php?param1=one&param2=two"
```

When this URL is included to href, of course i've encoded like:

```
"http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com%2Findex.php%3Fparam1%3Done%26param2%3Dtwo"
```

(actually this is what like generator gave me)

But it's very strange. when I check it on Graph API Explorer, it has been changed like:

```
"http://www.test.com/index.php%3Fparam1=one&param2=two"
```

It tells me that only "?" (Question mark) has not been decoded. Is it a current facebook bug? (actually it worked 5 days ago). I don't want to use apache with htaccess not to use question mark.